# why is my string not being a string?

Tags: javascript

Seeking some cheeky on the fly help here. Been staring at this for  along time and cannot see why the whole thing is not maintaining being a string:

```
var str = 
    '<script type="cats/conversion">
        {"type":"REGISTER",
         "params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + {{sku}} + '",
         "f":"' + {{accountHolderName}} + '",
         "e":"' + {{dl userid}} + '"}
        } 
    <\/script>';
```

I had expected that all of str is a string but my text editor is telling me that it's not. Where have I typeod a ' or "?

Help!!

Comment: Hi Tushar, I'm actually using the Google Tag Manager environment which {{ }} are related to macros within it. Pretty sure that's not the issue (directly at least)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (safely and reasonably) do multi-line string literals in JavaScript. You have to build them up using concatenation (the `+` operator). You can do it like this:

```
var str = '<script type="cats/conversion">' +
    '{"type":"REGISTER",' +
        '"params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + {{sku}} + '",' +
        '"f":"' + {{accountHolderName}} + '",' +
        '"e":"' + {{dl userid}} + '"}' +
'}' +
'<\/script>';
```

Note: I have no idea what the `{{sku}}` and similar placeholders in your script are. I assume those are for some templating system. They are not, as written, valid syntax.

**Edit:** Technically, as Alex pointed out in his answer, you can do multi-line literals by escaping the newline with `\`. As Alex says, however, this is "considered horrible practice" and prone to breaking for all kinds of reasons. Don't do it!

Comment: OK I did not know that thank you. I tried adding plus sign after like this but still no sucess: var str = 
    '<script type="cats/conversion">
  {"type":"REGISTER",
         "params":{
              "partner_conversion_id":" + {{sku}} +",
            "f":"' + {{accountHolderName}} + '",
            "e":"' + {{dl userid}} + '"} +
        } +
   <\/script>';

Comment: [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) can also be used.

Comment: Thank you so much I did not know this

Comment: This answer is incorrect because there are many ways to make inline-strings in Javascript, some that are perfectly safe.  Please see my answer below for examples.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan That's not a particularly constructive comment. If you'd like to explain *how* it's incorrect, then please do.

Comment: @EdCottrell I did, but somebody deleted my comments anyway.  The explanation is in my answer below.  It just seems against SO to see an accepted answer with +5 votes that is so clearly wrong.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan The deleted comments just say that my answer is "Waaaaay wrong," call it "garbage," and promote your answer. That is not an explanation of what is allegedly wrong with my answer. That's just noise.

Comment: @EdCottrell Trying to prevent misinformation by providing correct information is not "noise".  This question, with your accepted answer, are going to mislead future Javascript developers, not to mention confuse beginners who are trying to understand whether this is possible or not.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan It is noise if all you're doing is insisting that an answer is "wrong," "garbage," and "misinformation," with the goal of promoting your own answer. We've each provided our answers. Many voters and OP agree that my answer is helpful. If people want to vote for your answer, which leads off with how to do something in "HORRIBLE practice," they will. But **SO comments are not for this kind of discussion.** If you care to identify a problem with this answer, please do so. Please do not simply continue to insist that it's wrong and that yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = '<script type="cats/conversion">'+
        '{"type":"REGISTER",'+
         '"params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + sku + '",'+
         '"f":"' + accountHolderName + '",'+
         '"e":"' + dl_userid + '"}'+
        '} '+
    '<\/script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you have to add a `\` to the end of a line to indicate a multi-line string.  This is considered HORRIBLE practice, because if the `\` is followed by any whitespace, it will throw a syntax error.

```
var ok = "this is \
         my multiline string!";

var notOk = "this is \ 
         my multiline string!";
```

The 2nd is an error because there is a space after the `\` at the end of the line.

If you are using ES6, you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) with backticks instead:

```
var x = `This is my
         multiline string!`;
```

If ES6 is not an option and you don't want to follow bad practices by using `\`, concatenate multiple strings together or insert newlines in your string like so:

```
var myString = "this is line 1" + 
"               this is line 2" +
"               this is line 3";
```

or

```
var myString = "this is line 1\n               this is line 2\n               this is line 3";
```

Answer (score 0):

You either do it in one line

```
var str ='<script type="cats/conversion"> {"type":"REGISTER", "params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + {{sku}} + '", "f":"' + {{accountHolderName}} + '", "e":"' + {{dl userid}} + '"}} <\/script>';
```

For readability if you want it to be multi lined you have to concatenate the string.

```
var str = '<script type="cats/conversion">' +
          '{"type":"REGISTER",' +
          '"params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + {{sku}} + '",' +
          '"f":"' + {{accountHolderName}} + '",' +
          '"e":"' + {{dl userid}} + '"}' +
          '}' +
          '<\/script>';
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean to do this:

```
var str = 
    '<script type="cats/conversion">
    {"type":"REGISTER",
     "params":{"partner_conversion_id":"' + '{{sku}}' + '",
     "f":"' + '{{accountHolderName}}' + '",
     "e":"' + '{{dl userid}}' + '"}
    } 
    <\/script>';
```

The {{}}'s need to be wrapped in quotes.